# React i18n, how to have <a>in a translation?

Tags: reactjs, i18next

So I have this text:

```
"someText": "To apply, please <a href="https://example.com">click here</a>, and fill the form"
```

Of couse I can't use `t("someText")` cause that just inserts the text literally.

I think I can use the `<Trans />` component, but in the example that means having my translation twice?

```
"someText": "To apply, please <1>click here</1>, and fill the form"

<Trans i18nKey="someText">
  To apply, please <a href="https://example.com">click here</a>, and fill the form
</Trans>
```

Am I missing something?

EDIT: Tested doing this:

```
<Trans i18nKey="someText">
  x <a href="https://example.com">click here</a> x
</Trans>
```

and it works but it doesn't feel correct...

Answer (score 0):

```
<Trans
    i18nKey="comment.login"
    components={{
    span: <span onClick={() => router.push('/')} />,
    }}
></Trans>{' '}
```

Try to use that way you can change span to a

Comment: Not good explaining